# Can I replace Pt100 with an Pt1000?

Tags: sensor

I have an existing OMRON Temperature Controller with a temperature input requirement of Pt100. Is there other way to maximize my Pt1000 in order to used it as Pt100?

Answer (score 1):

A PT100 has 100 Ω resistance at 0°C. A PT1000 has 1000 Ω at 0°C. Any method you might employ that tries to turn a 1000 Ω device into a 100 Ω device will result in total inaccuracy of measurement at non-0°C temperatures.

Link: [here](https://www.picotech.com/library/application-note/pt100-platinum-resistance-thermometers)

If you put a 111.11 Ω resistor in parallel with the PT1000 you'd get 100 Ω at 0°C but, At 100°C a proper PT100 has 138.4 Ω whereas 1384 Ω (PT1000) in parallel with 111.11 Ω does not produce 138.4 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

Some controllers can be configured for different inputs but are supplied set to a particular sensor type. Check the manual.

Otherwise the best you could do would be to make it read correctly at a single temperature as Andy says, and if you do that the PID terms or hysteresis settings will be off by about 10:1 as well. Better to get the correct sensor or a new controller.